# Google Endpoints using only inside App Engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, maven-3, m2eclipse

When we create End Point, it has external address to access it. So, if I try to call it from another End Point it will use some traffic.

I want to create End Point available from outside (Api), and another end point for accessing to datastorage. Second End Point shouldn't have external access, and could be called only inside App Engine from another applications (first service with external address). Just for security and minimization traffic.

So, is it possible to create End Point that available only for another End point and applications from Container Engine? Or i should do it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your question rather vague. Are you trying to access one endpoint from within the same app engine application? You could extract the endpoint code into a static method and call that method. There's no good reason to use endpoints for such a scenario.

If you try to access your endpoint from another App Engine application:
Cloud Endpoints are public by default. If you restrict the access things like the Google JavaScript client won't work anymore because you'll block the proper discovery of your endpoints.
You can restrict access to your endpoints by injecting the HttpServletRequest into your endpoint @ApiMethod and filter by the requester's IP or a custom header. You could also inject the User object into your endpoint method and do a service account oauth authentication to access your endpoint from another app engine instance or project.

Hope this helps

Local access to AppEngine's datastore is possible through:
JPA, JDO, the low level API (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/) If you need a wrapper, i'm using Objectify in all my projects, but there's also slim3 (see link).

Comment: I want 2 separate services. One only for datastorage access, and another that can call this service. And to minimize traffic want to call this service for datastorage by local ip.

Comment: Why would you want to use an endpoint to access the datastore? That's a lot of HTTP overhead and serialization mumbo jumbo for such a simple thing. If you only want to access the datastore locally then don't wrap a web service around it. But if you must, there is this: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/apis/v1beta2/

Comment: "If you only want to access the datastore locally then don't wrap a web service around it" how can i do this? All examples and maven skeleton projects have web service around it...

Comment: I added a link to my original answer. The low level API is acually pretty simple to use.

Comment: Yes, i will use it in my service that works with datastorage. But i want to separate logic: api in one service and data access in another.

Comment: Take a look at App Engine modules. I don't see any good reason to separate the data access layer from the api layer with services. You could create a jar library for your data access layer and use that in your api service. That's enough capsulation/separation i'd say. I admire that you want to keep your services clean and separated, but as said before: wrapping data access in a web service will get you a lot of http overhead. It will make your application slower than it has to be.